# Question about the inner product/norm on $l^2$

Tags: functional-analysis

I learned about the space $l^2$.
The space $l^2$ is defined as $l^2:=\{(x_n)_n : \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n|^2< \infty \}$. The norm on $l^2$ is induced by its inner product, that is defined as $<v,w>:=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} v_n \overline{w_n}$.

It was mentioned that for the norm we need $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |v_n|^2$ to be finite. And for the inner product, we need to check that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |v_n w_n|$ is finite.

I do understand why we need to check that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |v_n|^2$ is finite. It is because this is one necessary condition that the norm really is a norm (the other follow quite easily).
But I do not see why we need $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |v_n w_n|$ to be finite. I am assuming that it is a very similar reason as for the norm. But I don't see how we get from $<v,w>:=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} v_n \overline{w_n}$ to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |v_n w_n|$. Or in other words, how $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |v_n w_n|< \infty$ ensures that the inner product stays finite.

Answer (score 1):

$\sum|v_n\overline{w_n}|\le\sqrt{\sum|v_i|^2\sum|w_j|^2}<\infty$ by Cauchy-Schwarz, and [this absolute convergence of $\sum v_n \overline{w_n}$ ensures its ordinary convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence#Proof_that_any_absolutely_convergent_series_of_complex_numbers_is_convergent).

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$\vert \sum_{n \geq 1} v_n \overline{w_n} \vert \leq \sum_{n \geq 1} \vert v_n \vert \vert \overline{w_n} \vert = \sum_{n \geq 1} \vert v_n \vert \vert w_n \vert$$
by the triangle inequality and equality can be attained when $w = \alpha v.$